# Accessing an element of an object inside a multidimensional array inside an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js and my viewModel is an object with a multidimensional array inside it and I'm have trouble accessing a specific element. My code is:

```
var viewModel = {
    states: [
        new state("Virginia", [["Va Beach",[{lat:36.852926,lng:-75.977985}]], ["Chincoteague Island",[{lat:37.933179,lng:-75.378809}]]]),
        new state("Maryland", [["Atlantic City",[{lat:39.364283,lng:-74.422927}]], ["Ocean city",[{lat:38.336503,lng:-75.084906}]]]),
        new state("North Carolina", [["Oakacroke",[{lat:35.114615,lng:-75.98101}]], ["Nags Head",[{lat:35.957392,lng:-75.624062}]],["Emerald Isle",[{lat:34.677940,lng:-76.950776}]]])
        ]
};

var state = function(name, city) {
    this.name = name;
    this.city = ko.observableArray(city);
}
```

I'm trying to get the lat and lng of each individual city. I've played around with with JSON.stringify and filter but havent been able to isolate the lan and lng specifically.

http://codepen.io/ntibbs/pen/vNMKzg?editors=101

Comment: without knowing of `state()` it is not possible to say how to access the properties.

Comment: You can access the properties of the cities of each state like this: `viewModel.states[0].city[0][1][0].lat`. Note that to loop over them you would need two loops, one for state, one for city, and then use `viewModel.states[nState].city[nCity][1][0].lat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of the `foreach:city` binding, you would need to do something like this:

```
<span data-bind="text: $data[1][0].lat"></span>
<span data-bind="text: $data[1][0].lng"></span>
```

Basically, you `states` array has a property called `city` (bad name, it really ought to be `cities`) which is, itself, an array. So you need to index that array (which is what `foreach` is doing) and each item in that array is itself an array where the first item is the name of the city and the second is an array with a single object with the `lat` and `lng` properties you need.

So something like `viewModel.states[0].city[0][1][0].lat` would should give you `36.852926`

Of course, looking at how convoluted it is to access the properties you need, it is probably worth while to think about transforming it into something easier to work with.

Comment: I agree. I think reworking my data is the best path going forward to avoid more issues like this.

Comment: Yep - the data nesting seems excessive, and therefore difficult to deal with without coder-error.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, each *state* object has a name, and contains an array of places.

Each place contains an array with a single element - a latitude, longitude pair.
e.g.

```
("Virginia",   
   [  
      [
          "Va Beach",
              [
                  {lat:36.852926,lng:-75.977985}
              ]  
      ]  
   ]
)
```

So
`locationOfPlace = aState[aPlaceName][1]`

And to refer to each property:
`latitudeOfPlace = aState[aPlaceName][1].lat`
`longitudeOfPlace = aState[aPlaceName][1].lng`

Answer (score 0):

You've made an odd decision to wrap the lat/lon object in an array, as if a city might have multiple coordinates attached to it.

I think it would help clear up your design if, in addition to having a `state` object, you had a `city` object, rather than an object literal. Something like:

```
var city = function(name, lat, lon) {
    this.name = name;
    this.location = {
        lat: lat,
        lon: lon
    };
};
```

Then you'd declare a state more like:

```
new state("Virginia", [
  new city("Va Beach", 36.852926, -75.977985),
  new city("Chincoteague Island", 37.933179, -75.378809)
]);
```

and you might access city properties like so:

```
state.city()[0].location.lat
```